# How to open to the dynamic page path in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use the dynamic path by using nextjs app.

I am developing a CMS system and my pages run through nextjs.

In my react admin application, user can add and design multiple pages.
There is an end-user  nextjs application which allow the users to get these dynamic pages.

For example: Application Admin added aboutus page and now user can access this page by typing the following in the browser.

```
http://localhost:3000/aboutus
```

This should work but it doesn't. The First thing is nextjs give an error when we try to use `useRouter hook` and get a `pathname` (it shows an error) and try to find the aboutus.js page component which doesn't exist physically.

Second thing is that we need a react component something like `App.js component` so that we can identify the dynamic page and call our logic to show the page but in nextjs there is nothing like `App.js component` nor `index.js` component. Nextjs has MyApp.js component which is a start point to trigger each page component with its properties but I can't write the logic here.

What I want is that to access the dynamic pages using dynamic route path. following should work

```
http://localhost:3000/aboutus
http://localhost:3000/contact
```

Please see my code below

```
========================================package.json==================================
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "next": "11.0.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",      
        "swr": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "7.29.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1"
    },
}

=================================================MyApp======================================

import "../styles/styles.css";
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <SharedProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </SharedProvider>
    );
}
export default MyApp;




 ==========================================================index.js=======================

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Head from "next/head";
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout";
function Home({ resData }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { permalink } = router.query;
    const [pageId, setPageId] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        onLoad();
    }, []);
    function onLoad() {

        let range = document.createRange();
        const wrapper = document.querySelector(".ic-container");
        wrapper.innerHTML = "";
        wrapper.appendChild(range.createContextualFragment(resData.PageContent));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{resData.Title}</title>
                <meta property="og:description" name="description" content={resData.MetaDescription} key="description" />
                <meta property="og:keywords" name="keywords" content={resData.Keywords} key="keywords" />
                <meta property="og:title" name="title" content={resData.MetaTitle} key="title" />
                <meta property="og:author" name="author" content="test" key="author" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/minimalist-blocks/content.css" />
                <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
                <script
                    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                    integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                ></script>

            </Head>
            <Layout>
                <div className="ic-container">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { perm } = context.query;
    let resData = "";
    try {    
        const fetchResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/asa/page/pageByPer/" + perm);
        const data = await fetchResponse.json();
        const responseData = data && data.page && data.page.length > 0 ? data.page[0] : "";
        initialData = responseData;
        if (data) {
            if (data.isExist > 0) {
                lpageId = responseData.Id;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } finally {
    }
    return {
        props: {
        resData,
        },
    };
}

export default Home;
```

What is the best fix for it ? thank you for the help

[image]

Comment: What does your file structure under `/pages` look like? Have you actually defined a dynamic page?

Comment: /pages/index.js , /pages/_app.js.

Comment: If the goal is to use a dynamic path, the first step would be to setup a [Dynamic Route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

Comment: Hi, thank you juli. Here is some confusion which i want to understand. I have read this page. Will dynamic route work when user n user ll  enter url in the browser. Like user enter http://localhost:3000/dynamicpage
There  is no definion of this page. There is no dynamicpage.js under pages directory. What do you say now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Juliomalves is right.

Create a component like this [page].js under pages directory.

Following 'll work. Please try following

```
const Page = ({ resData }) => {
const router = useRouter();   
const { page } = router.query;
    const [pageId, setPageId] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        onLoad();
    }, []);
    function onLoad() {

        let range = document.createRange();
        const wrapper = document.querySelector(".ic-container");
        wrapper.innerHTML = "";
        wrapper.appendChild(range.createContextualFragment(resData.PageContent));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{resData.Title}</title>
                <meta property="og:description" name="description" content={resData.MetaDescription} key="description" />
                <meta property="og:keywords" name="keywords" content={resData.Keywords} key="keywords" />
                <meta property="og:title" name="title" content={resData.MetaTitle} key="title" />
                <meta property="og:author" name="author" content="test" key="author" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/minimalist-blocks/content.css" />
                <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
                <script
                    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                    integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                ></script>

            </Head>
            <Layout>
                <div className="ic-container">
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </Layout>
        </>
    );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { page } = context.query;
    let resData = "";
    try {    
        const fetchResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/asa/page/pageByPer/" + page );
        const data = await fetchResponse.json();
        const responseData = data && data.page && data.page.length > 0 ? data.page[0] : "";
        initialData = responseData;
        if (data) {
            if (data.isExist > 0) {
                lpageId = responseData.Id;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } finally {
    }
    return {
        props: {
        resData,
        },
    };
}
```